# Seeking German Meir Family living in 1930s Łódź (Poland)?

Tags: 19th-century, 20th-century, poland

My great grand parents were Krzysztof & Magdelana Meier. They lived in Łódź, Poland. I have an address for Meiers in 1930.

My grandparents, Arno & Julianna Hennig, had 6 children 3 boys and 3 girls.

I am trying to determine if any other family members have survived.

What resources can I utilize to determine if others survived?

Comment: Welcome to G&FH SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format which is quite different from bulletin boards, discussion forums and other Q&A sites you may be used to.  Please try to ask a single focussed question rather than for "any stories?"  In particular we need you to take care when asking about anyone born within the last 100 years because there is a Privacy Policy in the [help/on-topic].

Comment: When were Arno and Julianna born?

Answer (score 1):

I think it's him: https://unknown-jewelsjournal-unknown.blogspot.com/2012/10/our-dad-arno-hennig.html. I hope it's your relative.